# Jquery datepicker should get server date,

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible that JQuery datepicker should follow the server date rather than client date ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. definitely possible.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker(
              { defaultDate: <%= DateTime.Now.ToString("YOUR DATE FORMAT") %> });
```

Refer: [jQuery UI Datepicker default date](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

Comment: I Tried it but this did not highlight server date, it just make border of that date.

Comment: If you want a specific style for highlighting, you can always tweak the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

While page loading get the `date` from `server` and Just use that date  to set the `date` for the `datepicker`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the initial date based on a server side value:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

Just replace the date with some server side code that outputs it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is client side. If you want to get some info from jQuery you have to load content via ajax.
You can set the date via asp code to the input field or when you call the datepicker method

```
<input type="text" value="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("DATE FORMAT") %>" />
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: <%= DateTime.Now.ToString("DATE FORMAT") %> });
```